# Access Violation Exception in Unmanaged Code when using OdbcDataAdapter.Fill in Background Thread

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, odbc

I am experimenting with Threads to try and learn a bit about them. I wrote a little WPF app that starts uses a background Thread to poll an ODBC source on an interval, retrieving the data into a DataTable via OdbcDataAdapter.Fill and writing it to a CSV file.

Every so often, the app encounters an AccessViolationException. The timing varies, sometimes it can run for a few days before encountering it, other times just a day. So far it has not ever happened as a result of UI interaction.

The Thread (LoggingThread in the stack trace) is to have MainWindow control it via calls to MyApp which manages LoggingThread via ManualResetEvents and CancellationTokenSource. LoggingThread itself is runs a continuous loop managed by the aforementioned ManualResetEvents.

I've used DataAdapter successfully in other single-threaded projects before, so I guess it could be something about how I'm handling LoggingThread that's setting up conditions for this exception to occur, because the polling code is quite simple:

```cs
if (!this._cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(this.connStr))
    {
        using (var adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(this.sql, conn))
        {
            try
            {
            int rows = adapter.Fill(table);
            }
            catch() { // log Exception(s) }
            finally
            {
                adapter.Dispose();
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
    }        
}
```

What could cause this? Is there some mitigating action that I can take to avoid it?

Let me know if you need other code snippets to more fully understand this.

The exception details:

```
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
   at System.Data.Common.UnsafeNativeMethods.SQLMoreResults(System.Data.Odbc.OdbcStatementHandle)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcStatementHandle.MoreResults()
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.NextResult(Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.Close(Boolean)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.Dispose(Boolean)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.Dispose()
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(System.Data.DataSet, System.Data.DataTable[], Int32, Int32, System.String, System.Data.IDbCommand, System.Data.CommandBehavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(System.Data.DataTable[], Int32, Int32, System.Data.IDbCommand, System.Data.CommandBehavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(System.Data.DataTable)
   at MyApp.LoggingThread.PollServer(System.Data.DataTable)
   at MyApp.LoggingThread.LoggingHandler()
   at MyApp.MyApp.<StartProcessing>b__0()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the LoggingHandler() method referenced in the stack trace, maybe it'll help.

```cs
DataTable table = new DataTable();
while (true)
{

   this.pauseEvent.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite);
    if (this.stopEvent.WaitOne(0))
    {
        break;
    }

    PollServer(table);

    if (table != null && table.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
         WriteData(table);
         table.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
         table = new DataTable();
    }

    if (!this._cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        this.loopingEvent.WaitOne(this.delaySpan);
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be that the native dependencies are not thread-safe, and you're causing an crash in them, which then surfaces as an AccessViolationException to the managed code.

Answer (score 0):

The using statement works only on disposable objects.  So as a result...

```
using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(this.connStr))
{
    //...
}
```

The using statement translates to:

```
OdbcConnection conn = null;
try
{
     conn = new OdbcConnection(this.connStr);
     // other code
}
finally
{
    if (conn != null)
        conn.Dispose();
}
```

Your multiple and unnecessary calls to Dispose() may present a problem.  Especially where you are calling Close() on the connection after it has been disposed in your nested try / finally block.  However I don't believe this is the full story.  More code is necessary to determine the other issue(s).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I was using "using" and still failed.  I realized that it was the following line,

```
Using cmd As System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand = objConn.CreateCommand()
End Using
```

My issue was because I was passing the connection object through, to keep the connection open and I was creating lots of `ObdcCommand` objects...